# Was Nigerian COAS Gen. Faruk Yahaya actually arrested/imprisoned?

Tags: military, rule-of-law, nigeria

There are [various](https://punchng.com/court-orders-arrest-imprisonment-of-army-chief/) [stories](https://theconversation.com/contempt-of-court-in-nigeria-what-the-cases-of-three-convicted-security-officials-tell-us-195947) from Dec last year that Nigeria's Chief of Army Staff, general [Faruk Yahaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faruk_Yahaya) was sentenced to jail or prison for contempt of court.

> The chief of army staff was also jailed for contempt for failure to obey a court order issued on 12 October 2022 in a suit between a citizen and the governor of Niger state, north-central Nigeria.

Was he actually arrested/imprisoned though? I could find no follow-up stories confirming that. OTOH there are lengthy puff pieces lauding him, published [later](https://prnigeria.com/2023/04/29/unique-army-chief-faruk-yahaya/). And he was [talking](https://www.naijanews.com/2023/03/26/its-not-true-army-chief-denies-allegations-in-reuters-report/) to Reuters in March, from his office.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is almost certainly "no". A Dec 8 article notes [that](https://dnllegalandstyle.com/2022/contempt-how-army-police-efcc-others-are-endangering-rule-of-law/)

> but none of them were arrested.

And a brief [note](https://von.gov.ng/court-vacates-order-against-chief-of-army-staff/) on a government website (that seems to have received almost no press coverage) on Jan 17 says that the same judge vacated the contempt order against the COAS, because the general apparently complied with whatever he had been ordered to do (which is actually not clearly spelled out in most of these stories.)